# Responsive font with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, text, fonts

I have the following code for responsive fonts:

```
@media all and (max-width: 1200px) { /* screen size until 1200px */
    body {
        font-size: 1.5em; /* 1.5x default size */
    }
}
@media all and (max-width: 1000px) { /* screen size until 1000px */
    body {
        font-size: 1.2em; /* 1.2x default size */
        }
    }
@media all and (max-width: 500px) { /* screen size until 500px */
    body {
        font-size: 0.8em; /* 0.8x default size */
        }
    }
```

I dont know how can I set the 'default size'. For example 1.5em font-size how many pxs are? 14px? 12px?.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is the body font-size, 1.5em should equal to 24px.
**em** always use his parent element as its base but, relative em or **rem** doesn't use his immediate parent; It uses the html or body font-size.
e.g.

```
body{
  font-size:1em = 16px
}
.container{
  font-size:1em = 16px
  font-size:0.75em = 12px
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple formula to convert from px to em:

```
Size in em = size in pixels / parent size in pixels
```

**Example**: 21px / 14px = 1.5em

and back:

```
Size in px = size in EMs * parent size in pixels
```

**Example**: 1.5em * 14px = 21px

PS: 14px is the default font size in Bootstrap. [Source](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-body-copy): Bootstrap CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The `em` unit always uses the unit of the parent element as the base.

e.g. if your `body` has a `font-size` of `12px`, then setting `1em` on a child element would also render it with `12px` (1em = 100%)

From then on, you can use sites like http://pxtoem.com/ to calculate the appropriate `em` values you're trying to achieve

You may also just refer to percents (`1.5em` = `150%`, `2em` = `200%` and so on...)